# fastNlMeansDenoising() does not filter out noise

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to remove noise by opencv fastNlMeansDenoising() function. 
But My output image is same like original noised image.

**Input image:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;

using namespace cv;


int main() {

    Mat img = imread("noisy.jpg");

    if (!img.data) {
        cout << "File not found" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // first copy the image
    Mat img_gray = img.clone();
    cvtColor(img, img_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    Mat img1;
    //fastNlMeansDenoising(img_gray, img1, 3.0, 7, 21);
    cv::fastNlMeansDenoising(img_gray, img1, 3.0, 7, 21);

    imshow("img1", img1);

    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output Image:**

[image]

I can not see any effect of smoothing. I do not understand reason of it. 
Please help me to use this function for removing noise. thanks

Comment: Not sure if it may be related to your problem, but you don't have to do `img.clone()`. `cvtColor` will create the output image for you.

Comment: I have corrected it. but still output image is not De noising image.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In OpenCV, the function is defined as follows

```
void fastNlMeansDenoising(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, float h=3, int templateWindowSize=7, int searchWindowSize=21 )
```

where

> Parameters:    src – Input 8-bit 1-channel, 2-channel or 3-channel
>
> image. dst – Output image with the same size and type as src .
>
> templateWindowSize – Size in pixels of the template patch that is used
> to compute weights. Should be odd. Recommended value 7 pixels
>
> searchWindowSize – Size in pixels of the window that is used to
> compute weighted average for given pixel. Should be odd. Affect
> performance linearly: greater
>
> searchWindowsSize - greater denoising
> time. Recommended value 21 pixels
>
> h – Parameter regulating filter
> strength. Big h value perfectly removes noise but also removes image
> details, smaller h value preserves details but also preserves some
> noise

Therefore, in order to remove noise, I had to increase the filter strength parameter `h`, big h value perfectly removes noise, but a smaller h value preserves details and also preserve some noise.

So I perfectly removed the noise by using the function like this:

```
fastNlMeansDenoising(img_gray, img1, 30.0, 7, 21);
```

**Output:**

[image: denoise image with filter strength 30]

**Note:** This function's execution time is too slow in debug mode. For a little bit faster execution time, better to run it in release mode.