# OpenCV Image Denoising gives: Error: -215:Assertation failed

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing, noise

Trying to denoise a really simple image, using the code below. When printing out the array of data I get the following structure, which is expected as the image is greyscale:

```
[[ 62  62  63 ...  29  16   6]
 [ 75  90 103 ...  21  16  12]
 [ 77 100 118 ...  29  29  30]
 ...
 [ 84  68  56 ...  47  50  53]
 [101  94  89 ...  40  44  48]
```

Here is the code and the associated error, at this point I'm a little stuck. Any suggestions?

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread(path,0)
dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(img,None,10,10,7,21)

plt.subplot(211),plt.imshow(dst)
plt.subplot(212),plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

____________________________________________________________________
runfile(___, wdir='G:/James Alexander/Python Programs')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-127-ce832752c183>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('G:/James Alexander/Python Programs/Noiseremoval.py', wdir=___)

  File "___", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "___", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "___", line 13, in <module>
    dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(img,None,10,10,7,21)

error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\photo\src\denoising.cpp:120: error: (-215:Assertion failed) hn == 1 || hn == cn in function 'cv::fastNlMeansDenoising'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation on the [Denoising function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d79/group__photo__denoise.html#ga4c6b0031f56ea3f98f768881279ffe93) that you're using. There are two ways to call the function and you seem to be doing a combination of the two.

`dst = cv.fastNlMeansDenoising(src[, dst[, h[, templateWindowSize[, searchWindowSize]]]])`

or

`dst = cv.fastNlMeansDenoising(src, h[, dst[, templateWindowSize[, searchWindowSize[, normType]]]])`

You are calling it with `(src, dst, h, templateWindowSize, searchWindowSize, normType)` which either has too many parameters or is in the wrong order, depending on which method you want to use.

Comment: Thank you, changed this now to ````dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(img,None,3,7,11)```` however the noise removal isn't even slightly working, any suggestions into which parameters are to blame?

Comment: You need a higher filter strength. See [this old question/answer about the same function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37921901/10530885) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

change your parameters to

```
dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(img, None, 30, 7, 21)
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on why this is likely the solution? Giving some information about what the arguments mean will be more likely to help future readers and not just the author.